# SwiftUI Tutorial: Scrumdigger Spacer() issue

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have been working through the SwiftUI Scrumdigger tutorial (https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/getting-started-with-scrumdinger) and have reached Step 7 of "Creating a Card View". Here is where my experience deviates from what is presented by the tutorial.

Here is the code both I and the tutorial are using:

```
import SwiftUI

struct CardView: View {
    let scrum: DailyScrum
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(scrum.title)
                .font(.headline)
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Label("\(scrum.attendees.count)", systemImage: "person.3")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CardView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var scrum = DailyScrum.sampleData[0]
    static var previews: some View {
        CardView(scrum: scrum)
            .background(scrum.theme.mainColor)
            .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 400, height: 60))
    }
}
```

Here is what I see:

[image]

And here is what the tutorial displays:

[image]

I have tried moving the `Spacer()` from line 9 to line 13 but the issue is the same.

Can reproduce without the reliance on the external Scrum data using this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct CardView: View {
    //let scrum: DailyScrum
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Title")
                .font(.headline)
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Label("3", systemImage: "person.3")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CardView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    //static var scrum = DailyScrum.sampleData[0]
    static var previews: some View {
        CardView()
            .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 400, height: 60))
    }
}
```

Can anyone advise as to what might be going wrong here?

Comment: You could add a Spacer before `Text("Title")` and after the `HStack`. But the View itself is correct. You are using the live preview which puts the view into an iPhone. Assuming you are using Xcode 14+ you can change the preview from Live to Selectable (bottom left of the preview canvas)

Comment: Using selectable preview mode at the bottom leading of the canvas. You ảe using Live Preview which will use a device instead of frame